# DNS Forward Lookup Zone disappeares on transfer

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2

My Forward Lookup Zones keep disappearing from the DNS servers. I got 2 servers with Active Directory and Domain Conntrollers. As long as the Forward Lookup Zone for the domain dont get replicated from one server to the other everything is ok. Only when I configure a zone transfer, at first everything seems fine and the zone gets copied to the other server but after a few minutes the entire zone is gone on both servers.
What is happening?

ps. Windows Server 2012 r2

Comment: Are you trying to do a zone transfer from one active directory controller to another on the same domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Active Directory integrated DNS zones are replicated between domain controllers by the Active Directory replication mechanism. Setting up zone transfers between the two is unnecessary, will interfere with Active Directory replication and cause unpredictable behaviour. Don't do it.